# How does one use Tensorflow's OpOutputList?

Tags: tensorflow

On the github, an OpOutputList is initialized like so:

```
OpOutputList outputs;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->output_list("output",&outputs));
```

And tensors are added like this:

```
Tensor* tensor0 = nullptr;
Tensor* tensor1 = nullptr;
long long int sz0 = 3;
long long int sz1 = 4;
...
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, outputs.allocate(0, TensorShape({sz0}), &tensor0));
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, outputs.allocate(1, TensorShape({sz1}), &tensor1));
```

I'm assuming that OpOutputList is like OpInputList in that jagged arrays are allowed.

My question is, how does OpOutputList work? Sometimes I get segfaults where I can't access the first index when I use `Eigen::Tensor::flat()` but because I don't understand how allocation works I can't pinpoint the error.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpOutputList object itself is a very simple value object containing just two integers - the start and end indices of the op outputs that are contained in this list. Being simple value objects, you generally just create them on the stack, no "allocation" required.

You allocate the tensors that logically belong to an OpOutputList just like any other tensor. Generally using allocate_output(). Here is the implementation of `OpOutputList::allocate`:

```
Status OpOutputList::allocate(int i, const TensorShape& shape,
                              Tensor** output) {
DCHECK_GE(i, 0);
DCHECK_LT(i, stop_ - start_);
return ctx_->allocate_output(start_ + i, shape, output);
}
```

As you can see it just checks that the index `i` is indeed within this `OpOutputList` and call `allocate_output`.